# How to just host a single JS file at a domain with with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to host a JavaScript file that users can import.

I have a Firebase project and added a site for this (already bought the domain and handled all the DNS steps involved with that). I changed my firebase config to look like this so that the domain would serve a JavaScript file instead of public/index.html:

```
{
  "hosting": [{
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/[js_file_to_serve].js"
    }],
    "target": "[project_name]",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }]
}
```

I'm still only seeing the `Firebase Hosting Setup Complete` page, however.

Comment: What is `[js_file_to_serve]` meant to be? Do you have  a file in your `public` directory?

Comment: If you are making a request to the root of the domain `example.com/`, make sure you delete `index.html`. Files will take precedence over rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

@abraham got it - you can't have an index.html file in your public directory or else it will take precedence. Thanks!